# Parsing error when trying to play Cardboard SDK For Unity Demo First time

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I have followed the getting started steps here:
https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/get-started

But when I load the .apk file to my phone, I get a "There was a problem parsing the package" error.

I tried searching online and I assume it means I have an issue somewhere in my AndroidManifest.xml file?

Is there anything else I need to be aware of that the get-started guide didn't mention?

Comment: Please post your error also.

Comment: It just says "Parsing error" in the title of the box and "There is a problem parsing the package" in the body when I open the .apk on my phone. My settings allow unknown sources btw.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution!

Open the Android manifest file inside **YourProject/Assets/Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml** and change the value of **android:minSdkVersion to 16**. It was 19 by default.

If it helps I'm doing this on a Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android version 4.1.2